# Proper way to setInterval and clearInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

Relative newcomer to JS, trying to wrap my head around the scheduling. This code will start the appending but not stop it. I'm pretty sure that the problem is that 'clearInterval' needs to address a variable which has been assigned a 'setInterval' function. What I can't seem to grasp is how to properly phrase that.

```
var hmm = function appendStuff(){
    $("p").append("<b>Appended text</b>");
};
$("#start").click(function() {   
    console.log("startClicked");  // working... 
    window.setInterval(hmm, 1000) // working...
}); 
$("#stop").click(function() {   
    console.log("stopClicked");  // working...  
    window.clearInterval(hmm)
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Based on https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp It looks like you need to apply `clearInterval ` to the return value of `setInterval` but not the function your set interval for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setInterval()` function returns an ID. This is what you want to assign to `hmm`.

Also, the first parameter of `setInterval()` is the function you want to call every interval.

```
var hmm = null;
function appendStuff(){
    $("p").append("<b>Appended text</b>");
};
$("#start").click(function() {   
    console.log("startClicked");  // working... 
    hmm = window.setInterval(appendStuff, 1000) // working...
}); 
$("#stop").click(function() {   
    console.log("stopClicked");  // working...  
    window.clearInterval(hmm)
});
```

Comment: *"Also, the first parameter of setInterval() is the function you want to call every interval."* - Yes, and that is what the OP's code already does.

Comment: I know. But since we already changed what the value of hmm is, I am just clarifying that it should not be hmm anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the setInterval object to a variable and pass it to clearInterval, not the funciton variable of SetInterval into clearInterval. Refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp).

```
var hmm = function appendStuff(){
    $("p").append("<b>Appended text</b>");
};
var interval;
$("#start").click(function() {   
    console.log("startClicked");  // working... 
    interval = window.setInterval(hmm, 1000) // working...
}); 
$("#stop").click(function() {   
    console.log("stopClicked");  // working...  
    window.clearInterval(interval)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this setInterval() example from w3School [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_setinterval_clearinterval). Basically you use syntax like for example:

```
var yourIntervalVariable = setInterval(function(){
  // do something here..
}, 1000);
```

And then you can use clearInterval() on the variable like this:

```
clearInterval(yourIntervalVariable);
```